# warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, warnings

how can i get rid of the warning "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency" while writing my code ?

This is a part of the code and the warning i get

```js
useEffect(() => {
        if(inactive){
            document.querySelectorAll('.sub-menu').forEach((el) => {
                el.classList.remove("active");
            });
                    }

                    
        props.onCollapse(inactive);
    }, [inactive]);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to include `props` in dependency array.

```
useEffect(() => {
// your code
}, [props, inactive]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include `props.onCollapse` as a dependency.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // ...
}, [props.onCollapse, inactive]) // ✅
```

You should **not** pass the entire `props` object as another answer suggests.

And there is something else happening in your code that also needs attention. See how you are using `document.querySelector` and `classList` remove?

```js
 document.querySelectorAll('.sub-menu').forEach((el) => {
  el.classList.remove("active"); // ⚠️ react is not jQuery
});
```

This is an anti-pattern in react. Instead your Menu component should render submenu `classNames` as a pure function of the menu state.

```js
function Menu({ items = [], initState = true }) {
  const [active, setActive] = React.useState(initState)
  const onClick = event => { event.stopPropagation(); setActive(!active) }
  return active // ✅ data-driven render
    ? <div className="menu" onClick={onClick}>
        {items.map((item, key) =>
          Array.isArray(item)
            ? <Menu key={key} items={item} />
            : <MenuItem key={key} item={item} />
        )}
      </div>
    : <div className="menu" onClick={onClick}>
        <MenuItem item={items[0]} />
      </div>
}
```

<kbd>Run</kbd> the code below and click some menu items to see them toggle open and closed. Notice `useEffect`, `document.query*` and `classList` effects are not needed.

```js
function Menu({ items = [], initState = true }) {
  const [active, setActive] = React.useState(initState)
  const onClick = event => { event.stopPropagation(); setActive(!active) }
  return active
    ? <div className="menu" onClick={onClick}>
        {items.map((item, key) =>
          Array.isArray(item)
            ? <Menu key={key} items={item} />
            : <MenuItem key={key} item={item} />
        )}
      </div>
    : <div className="menu" onClick={onClick}>
        <MenuItem item={items[0]} />
      </div>
}

function MenuItem({ item }) {
  return <div>{item}</div>
}

const mymenu = [ "Main Menu",
  ["Clothing", "Shirts", "Pants", ["Footwear", "Shoes", "Boots"]],
  ["Accessories", "Bags", "Hats"]
]

ReactDOM.render(<Menu items={mymenu} />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
.menu {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```